# Iterate through non public member data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Running the risk of being shouted down for lack of examples but I'm trying to access all of the property names/values from a list of non public members of an object:

[image]

Tried this which returns null:

```
var temp = (cbBasket).GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(cbBasket));
```

And this which returns the type but not the value + plus the list contained over 90 key value pairs so I doubt if this is correct (!)

```
            Type myBasket = cbBasket.GetType();
            var myMemberInfo = myBasket.GetMembers();

            for (int i = 0; 1 < myMemberInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                var zString = myMemberInfo[i].Name + " " + myMemberInfo[i].MemberType;
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
C

Comment: The list of 90 values in your screenshot aren't private members of the `cbBasket` variable; they're values stored in a private `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` field called `m_dict`, which is a member of the `Params` class instance stored in the private `m_params` field on the `cbBasket` variable.

Comment: ^^ ... and it's probably private for a reason ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through [the source code](https://github.com/chargebee/chargebee-dotnet), it seems you want something like this:

```
ChargeBee.Api.Params parameters = cbBasket.Params();
var dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)typeof(ChargeBee.Api.Params)
    .GetField("m_dict", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(parameters);
```